# Include field in Rails user form, but not in params[:user] hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hash

I'm trying to create a form for `user` creation. In that form, they specify   a `team` they want to join. Each `team` has a password associated with it to facilitate joining that `team`. I'm trying to include that in the form, but naturally it ends up getting included in the `params[:user]` hash. This is annoying because I don't need that information to create the new `user` record. Is there a way to include this password in the field for verification in the controller, but not have it included in the `params[:user]` hash? If not, is there a clean way to remove unneeded values from the hash during `user` creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`password_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-password_field_tag) rather a `password_field` and place it inside the form.

The form can be either created with a form builder

```
<%= form_for @user do %>
  <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

or with a simple `form_tag`.

```
<%= form_tag ... do %>
  <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

In this way, even if you use a form builder, the field will be passed as a top level param and will not be nested inside the user params. You'll be able to fetch it with `params[:password]`.

Another option is to leave it inside the user attributed and delete the value from the `Hash`, however I personally don't like to modify input params whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to remove the `team_password` from the `params[:user]`:

```
  def user_params
    params[:user].except(:team_password)
  end
```

If you already have `user_params` defined in your controller, then you can just chain `.except(:team_password)` with your existing `user_params` method:

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(.....).except(:team_password)
  end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm explaining myself well enough. The user needs to input the password, but once it's been used to validate that they can join a given team, it's no longer needed for user creation, so I'm trying to move it out of the params[:user] hash. In trying the method you showed, the team_password value is still in params[:user] as well. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: you can delete that from the hash like this in your controller: `params[:user].delete :team_password `

Comment: Or, you can also do this: `params[:user].except(:team_password)` like my updated answer.

Comment: Oh that's great to know. Thanks for your help!